# CSS not loading in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to  spring frame work and spring boot.I am trying to add the static html file with CSS,javascript,js. the file structure is

[image: PROJECT STRUCTURE]

and my html file head looks like this

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>HeavyIndustry by HTML5Templates.com</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/5grid/core.css" th:href="@{css/5grid/core}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/5grid/core-desktop.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/5grid/core-1200px.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/5grid/core-noscript.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-desktop.css" />

    <script src="css/5grid/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="css/5grid/init.js?use=mobile,desktop,1000px&amp;mobileUI=1&amp;mobileUI.theme=none" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--[if IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
```

when i run the spring project only the content is shown and the CSS is not applied.then the browser show the following error in the console
     **404 Not Found error for the .css,.js files**

some body help me to sort out this issue.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have the same problem and i think the tomcat does not set permission to read the css folder. But i am new to spring-boot too and i don't have a solution.

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/modular

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to put your css in `/resources/static/css`. This change fixed the problem for me. Here is my current directory structure.

```
src
  main
    java
      controller
        WebAppMain.java
    resources
      views
        index.html
      static
        css
          index.css
          bootstrap.min.css
```

Here is my template resolver:

```
public class WebAppMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(WebAppMain.class);
    System.out.print("Starting app with System Args: [" );
    for (String s : args) {
      System.out.print(s + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
    app.run(args);
  }


  @Bean
  public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("XHTML");
    templateResolver.setPrefix("views/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");

    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(engine);
    return viewResolver;
  }
}
```

And just in case, here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring3-3.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Subscribe</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="text/css" href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<h1> Hello</h1>
<p> Hello World!</p>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it could be interesting add information about why we must put css file inside static folder.
It works for me too!

Comment: @FernandoSanchiz I assume thats just how the framework does things. I have no idea what the `why` is.

Answer (score 10):

Put *css* files into *webapp* resources folder:

```
src/main/webapp/resources/css/
```

Configure resource handler

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                        .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        }
```

Example projects:

- https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-web/tree/master/6/complete
- [Spring Boot Service Template with Static Content](https://github.com/jaylindquist/spring-boot-service-and-static)

Source:

- [Designing and Implementing a Web Application with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/web/)
- [Serving Web Content with Spring MVC](http://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

Comment: Also see [Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/docs/howto.md#serve-static-content) docs (probably more relevant in this particular case).

Comment: @MariuszS I have changed the folder structure as mentioned above.Now the index.html itself not loading.The Browser is showing the following error "HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers"

Comment: FYI: spring boot docs discourage putting content in webapp as it's not added to executable jars by default

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me after many attempts:

1. css location: `/resources/static/css/stylesheet.css`
2. link path in html: `th:href="@{/css/stylesheet.css}"`
3. WebSecurityConfig:

   ```
   @Override
   public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
       web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**");
   }
   ```

Comment: Good sample but WebSecurityConfig is not mandatory : It run perfectly without.

Answer (score 5):

Spring Boot will attempt to look in some default locations for your views.  Have a look at the following link.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties

If you're building an executable jar, your resources should be placed under src/main/resources, not src/main/webapp so that they're copied into your jar at build time.

Your index.html should go under src/main/resources/templates like you've got it, but your static resources shouldn't.  Spring Boot will look for your Thymeleaf views there by default.  And you don't actually need to define your own view resolver for Thymeleaf, Spring Boot will set this up for you if you have the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` dependency in your project.

```
# THYMELEAF (ThymeleafAutoConfiguration)
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html # ;charset=<encoding> is added
spring.thymeleaf.cache=true # set to false for hot refresh
```

As mentioned by others, if you put your css in src/main/resources/static/css or src/main/resources/public/css, then referencing them from href="css/5grid..." in your HTML should work.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issues and solved it the following way:

1. Make sure the folder you are exporting is available to the web

   ```
   public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

       private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
               "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
               "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/"
       };

       @Override
       public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
           registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                   .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
       }
   }
   ```

   In addition you must put your **css** or **styles** folder into your *src/main/resources/*(*static*|*public*|*resources*|*META-INF/resources*) folder
2. Make sure your security policies don't block them

   ```
   public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

       @Override
       public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
           //Web resources
           web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**");
           web.ignoring().antMatchers("/scripts/**");
           web.ignoring().antMatchers("/images/**");
       }
   }
   ```

That should be enough

Answer (score 2):

> In the case of Spring Boot, however, it’s worth mentioning how Spring
>   Boot deals with static content. When Spring Boot’s web
>   autoconfiguration is automatically configuring beans for Spring MVC,
>   those beans include a resource handler that maps /** to several
>   resource locations. Those resource locations include (relative to the
>   root of the classpath) the following:

1. /META-INF/resources/
2. /resources/
3. /static/
4. /public/

> In a conventional Maven/Gradle-built application, you’d typically put
>   static content at src/main/webapp so that it would be placed at the
>   root of the WAR file that the build produces. When building a WAR file
>   with Spring Boot, that’s still an option. But you also have the option
>   of placing static content at one of the four locations mapped to the
>   resource handler.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to spring boot too and I have the same problem.
I have put the correct path manually into the browser and have seen the 404 by tomcat.
Then I have found a solution at:
[Spring-Boot ResourceLocations not adding the css file resulting in 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733777/spring-boot-resourcelocations-not-adding-the-css-file-resulting-in-404?rq=1)

Now the css file is accessible by code.

You must move the css folder to src/main/resources/static/css then the content is readable (at my local configuration).

Answer (score 0):

```css
 <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
[this is the image for my project structure. i added the webapp directory to support .jsp files.this method request.getContextPath() worked for me. Hope i help someone with this... it gets the path so long as it exists. 
Nb. You should have a resolver bean in your webconfig
`enter code here`@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new   `enter code here`InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}` 
for the added directory][1]
```