# Spring-Boot ResourceLocations not adding the css file resulting in 404

Tags: css, spring, maven, spring-boot

Well i have a working spring-boot app that is running on a local computer just fine. However I noticed that when i do mvn package then none of my css or java scripts, locates in

```
/src/main/wepapp/css
```

are being copied into the jar file (package) created in the target directory.

spring boot reference guide says

> 65.3 Convert an existing application to Spring Boot "Static resources can be moved to /public (or /static or /resources or
>   /META-INF/resources) in the classpath root."
>
> 24.1.4 Static Content "Do not use the src/main/webapp folder if your application will be packaged as a jar. Although this folder is a
>   common standard, it will only work with war packaging and it will be
>   silently ignored by most build tools if you generate a jar."

So that means that i can  put all my js and css folders into the folder

```
/src/main/resources/static
```

i.e. now my structure looks like that

```
/src/main/resources/static/css/
/src/main/resources/static/js/
```

all of my thymeleaf templates however are still located in

```
/src/main/resources/templates/
```

I did that, and as far as i understand know i need to add the ResourceHandler to my ResourceHandlerRegistry. Previously when all of my ccs were in "/src/main/wepapp/css/" my ResourceHandlers looked like that and it worked very well for me.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/pdfs/**").addResourceLocations("/pdfs/").setCachePeriod(0);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/").setCachePeriod(0);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/").setCachePeriod(0);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/").setCachePeriod(0);

}
```

I have tried adding multiple handlers like

```
 registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/").setCachePeriod(0);
```

or

```
 registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/static/css/").setCachePeriod(0);
```

or

```
 registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/").setCachePeriod(0);
```

etc.

but none of them worked for me. 
The html templates are displayed but the web browser console is reporing 404 when trying to locate  /css/corresponing.css or /js/corresponing.js

I have deliberately disabled Spring security in my test project, in order to simplify debugging of this problem.

One more thing thing that i do not completely understand is the deployment assembly. I have read an article that said that when i do want to have particular folders into my target package jar file generated by maven, i do need to include those folder into my deployment assembly, well i did however "mvn package" is still not copping all of the content(inlcuding subfolders) of my  /src/main/static folder into the target jar file. I see however the "templates" folder copied into the jar file. So there is some other magic happening behind the scene.

[image]

Here is how do i declare the css in my thymeleaf  layout i.e.

```
/src/main/resources/templates/layout.html


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title layout:title-pattern="$DECORATOR_TITLE - $CONTENT_TITLE">Task List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"  th:href="@{/css/syncServer.css}"  href="../css/syncServer.css" />
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
      ...
  </body>
</html>
```

My question is: Is the configuration i done so far correct and if so what other options/settings i need to be aware of in order to make the app find the css files locates in /src/main/static/css/

Addition one

test project

```
git@github.com:TheDictator/sArchitecture.git
```

Comment: When using Spring Boot, if you add you resources to `/src/main/resources/static` you need any of the `addResourceHandlers` configuration. Spring Boot will take care of that stuff on it's own if of course you have used `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and have not used `@EnableWebMvc`

Comment: hello  geoand, i had used under one configuration class the @EnableWebMvc and now i have removed it but still the css are not beeing loaded. I have even comment the addResourceHandlers bean in order to check if those will be registered automatically. can you post a link regarding the the fact that we should not used EnableWebMvc

Comment: If you take a look at the source code of `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` you will see `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.class)`. That means that `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` is only used when `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` has not been configured as a bean, which in turn means when no `@EnableWebMvc` is present

Comment: If you still have problems, could you post your Spring configuration? I have used the resources the way I mentioned in my first comment and have no problem at all

Comment: Hello  geoand  It is stil not what i expected it to be. I will chop down the project and post the project in couple of hours on the github, then i will post the link here.  Thank you for your support.

Comment: Ok that sounds good! I'll clone it and test it out when you upload it

Comment: ok after i removed the @EnableWebMvc from that one location that i mentioned before and  did project clean and mvn clean i see that all of my css , images, pdf;s are copied in the root directory of the target jar file. So i was to quick with my last comment. However the css are still not displayed. Do i need to change the addResourceHandlers of completely remove them?

Comment: You should completely remove them since Spring Boot already configures the correct ones. I mean don't call the `addResourceHandlers` in your Spring configuration

Comment: hello geoand i have created a simple http only project that shows the problem with the css. I have uploaded the project on the github. The link is at the end of the question description

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you move you the whole `static` directory into the `resources` and totally remove the `addResourceHandlers` configuration, then everything works fine.

That means that resources structure would look like the following image:

[image]

Comment: Hello geoand , this is indeed working, i placed the static folder under the /src/main/resources/ directory and it all worked, however please help me understand what would be the correct path to use refering to the spring reference guide, would that me /src/main/resources/static/css or /src/main/static/css ? . if the path is /src/main/static/css then what would be the correct link to use i.e. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"  th:href="@{/css/syncServer.css}"
      href="../css/syncServer.css" />

Comment: thank you for the answer and for the support during this question

Comment: @Tito Your welcome! Check out http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content. It mentions the supported paths (relative to /resources).

Comment: english is not my native language but if i understand this correctly it will be /src/main/resources/static , /src/main/resources/resources , /src/main/resources/public ,, i am just a little bit confused because of the double resources folder in the second case