# Connecting .html file with Bootstrap's .css

Tags: java, css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, intellij-idea

I want to connect my .html file (containing Bootstrap's elements) with Bootstrap's .css file. I saw a lot of variants like:

```
<link href="resources/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

...but none of them was correct. In my case, I mean.

[How it looks when I include in my code some of these line](http://s5.ifotos.pl/img/webscreen_qrwrwre.jpg)

[How it looks when I include following line instead of these above:](http://s2.ifotos.pl/img/webscreen_qrwrwrq.jpg)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

The conclusion are such that the app can see .css from the Internet but there is some problem with local file. 
Here I sent .html file code:

```
http://wklej.org/id/3272762
```

If someone want to check folder structure, there is screenshot of my project in IntelliJ:

```
http://s6.ifotos.pl/img/idescreen_qrwrweq.jpg
```

I read on Stack there could be some problem with configuration but their solutions didn't seem appropriate considering fact that I use Spring Boot, not pure Spring without auto-config. Maybe there should be something added in application.properties? I saw also tips to put all .htmls with .css in one folder but... well, I don't think it is a good way.

Does someone know what I do wrong and what can I do to correct it to work properly?

## EDIT.

If you are looking for solution, please read comments directly under first post

Comment: Did you clear the browser's cache?

Comment: Yes, I did but unfortunately there's still something wrong

Comment: @ToTomki So relative to the HTML File where is the CSS file located? can you send the paths of the HTML and the CSS file?

Comment: Sometimes the easiest thing to do is to create another html file, another css file, and link those two together (to discart a problem in the way you link your original files)

Comment: @NarenMurali HTML files path: Propagander(main folder)/src/main/resources/templates; .css file path: Propagander/src/main/resources/static/css

Comment: @ToTomki Does it help you?

Comment: You can't develop anything without needing paths. So why not [learn it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing))? Web addresses use Unix-like paths. You also have examples there. Always (re)search before asking on [so].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733777/spring-boot-resourcelocations-not-adding-the-css-file-resulting-in-404?rq=1 

I did a little mess but here can be found some interesting info about a problem if someone is looking for solution of case like mine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this above the other links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Hope this works

Comment: As I said, when I include link to online .css file there is everything fine but I want to create connection to .css file in my .css directory ('cause even if I pass the problem this way, there will be the same problem when I want to use other .css file or when I want to edit previous one) :(

Answer (score 0):

I saw an error in file path you added here:

```
<link href="resources/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

instead write:

```
href="../../resources/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

EDIT:

```
href="../../static/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Comment: Still nothing. Thanks anyway for that you tried to help me ;)

Answer (score 0):

As I see in file structure templates too is under the `resources` so the path should be `href="../../static/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

Answer (score 0):

After receiving inputs of the Source HTML File and Bootstrap CSS file.

From the HTML file, `../` this will make it go one folder back which is `resources`, then go two folders forward `static/css/` then there the `bootstrap.min.css` will be found!

**HTML:**

```
Propagander(main folder)/src/main/resources/templates
```

**CSS:**

```
Propagander/src/main/resources/static/css
```

The correct link should be.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Please let me know if this fixes your issue!

Comment: Still doesn't work :(. Just in case, I added ".antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()" in config file but maybe Spring Security block .css file in some way?

Comment: @ToTomki Try opening the CSS link directly using the server URL, like `localhost:8888/src/main/resources/static/css/bootstrap.min.css`, please check the path also, if the path is correct and it says permission denied or something, then permissions is the issue I guess!

Comment: The result is whitelabel error page so probably the problem is the connection between .html and .css files

Comment: @ToTomki Place the CSS file in the same path as the template, reference it like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap.min.css">`, if this doesn't work, please confirm the source HTML file is actually the file path you are saying!

Comment: It's strange but the .html file stil doesn't see the .css file even if both of them are in the same folder.

Comment: Yes, it was. Unfortunately, I forgotten to come here and to post the solution. I don't remember the solution know but I know you gave me some tip what to look for. And thank you very much!