# Proper place to put static resources in my Spring Boot project

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot project I cannot get static resources such as css, images and java script file via web browser. Where is proper place to put whole bootstrap dictionary, or how to configure to get desired resources?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS not loading in Spring Boot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203402/css-not-loading-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Just create `static` folder in `src/main/resources` here: https://github.com/bajdekm/MailingHero/tree/master/src/main/resources and place them all there. If you don't create controller with mapping to root resource (something like `@RequestMapping("/")`), spring boot will serve static content from `index.html` automatically.

[Here is relevant section of Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content).