# SpringBoot does not load css when using uritemplating

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using springboot with thymeleaf to develop a website. The framework can load bootstrap css files cerrectly when not using uritemplating, but when I change to uritemplating then bootstrap css breaks.

This works perfectly

```
@GetMapping("/update_avatar")
public String update_avatar(){

    return "update_avatar";
}
```

This breaks css loading

```
@GetMapping("/update_avatar/{userid}")
public String update_avatar(@PathVariable String userid){

    System.out.println("Testing Variable: "+userid);
    return "update_avatar";
}
```

Here is how I include my stylesheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/main.css}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/tutors.css}"/>
```

Please note that I included Bootstrap using maven by doing the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried to implement viewRsolver based on this solution but it did not work for me [CSS not loading in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203402/css-not-loading-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Can you post your template code that includes the `<link...` element and tell us where the css file lives in the project directory structure?

Comment: I just included the snippets above, I used maven to include bootstrap in the project

Comment: Got it, have you added the resource handler (#4) http://www.baeldung.com/maven-webjars ?

Comment: Let me take a look at the article.

Comment: I just added resource handler, but I still can't have the problem solved. I also realised that it's all the css and js files that are not loading, it's not just bootstrap files.

Comment: Just occurred to me that you likely need to change your `webjars` to be absolute: `/webjars` not `webjars`. For the others, have a look at the rendered HTML and confirm that the paths are correct (_e.g._ they're rendering `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css"/>`)

Comment: Yeah... It actually works. This is weird because it works everything was working before I changed the URL to use URI templating. The only problem that is left is my stylesheet loading `main.css` and `tutors.css`, even though I made the changes you suggested

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164048/discussion-between-chris-thompson-and-mohale).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I finally got it to work even though 
I do not have a detailed explanation as to why the code did not work. I had this `@EnableWebMvc` annotation in my resource configurations class, and it was the one messing up everything. I had taken the annotation from the example on [this site](http://www.baeldung.com/maven-webjars) so if you know what it means, please do help with an explanation.

I also added 
    `registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("/webjars/");`
to my resource configurations class as Chris had suggested above.